# How to create vCard/vcf file to use in share sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, addressbook, abaddressbook

I'm new to swift and methods I am finding are deprecated regarding my issue.  I'm building a directory app and I'm pulling contact data from an API, not from the phone's address book.

In iOS, if you go to your address book, you can select a contact and choose 'Share Contact' which brings up a share sheet.  I want this exact functionality in my app.

I *think* I've got Share Sheets figured out, and here's my code for that:

```
    @IBAction func actShare(sender: AnyObject) {

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["text" as NSString], applicationActivities: nil)
    presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

I want to to change `"text" as NSString` to be a vCard, as that is the object that iOS shares from the address book, right?  Assuming I'm right, I want to create a vCard from my own app's contact object in order to share it to appropriate apps (email, sms, etc).

How can I achieve that in Swift? If I'm wrong, please correct me and show me what I need to do. Thanks.

EDIT: Okay, here's my changes.

```
@IBAction func actShare(sender: AnyObject) {
    do {
        var contactData = NSData()
        try contactData = CNContactVCardSerialization.dataWithContacts([createContact()])

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contactData as NSData], applicationActivities: nil)
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
    } catch {
        print("CNContactVCardSerialization cannot save address")
    }
```

and

```
func createContact() -> CNMutableContact {
    let contactCard = CNMutableContact()
    contactCard.givenName = "John"
    contactCard.familyName = "Doe"
    contactCard.emailAddresses = [
        CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: "john.doe@email.com")
    ]

    return contactCard
}
```

However, when I click the share button and it brings up my share sheet, I select the application I want to share to and it doesn't add/attach the contact data as intended.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick here is to save the contact to a VCard (.vcf) file using `CNContactVCardSerialization.dataWithContacts`, then pass the file URL to the `UIActivityViewController`. The activity view controller detects the VCard format from the file extension, and shows the apps where the format is supported (e.g. Messages, Mail, Notes, Airdrop, etc)

Example:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {

    let contact = createContact()

    do {
        try shareContacts([contact])
    }
    catch {
        // Handle error
    }
}

func shareContacts(contacts: [CNContact]) throws {

    guard let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first else {
        return
    }

    var filename = NSUUID().UUIDString

    // Create a human friendly file name if sharing a single contact.
    if let contact = contacts.first where contacts.count == 1 {

        if let fullname = CNContactFormatter().stringFromContact(contact) {
            filename = fullname.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").joinWithSeparator("")
        }
    }

    let fileURL = directoryURL
        .URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
        .URLByAppendingPathExtension("vcf")

    let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.dataWithContacts(contacts)

    print("filename: \(filename)")
    print("contact: \(String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")

    try data.writeToURL(fileURL, options: [.AtomicWrite])

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [fileURL],
        applicationActivities: nil
    )

    presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
}

func createContact() -> CNContact {

    // Creating a mutable object to add to the contact
    let contact = CNMutableContact()

    contact.imageData = NSData() // The profile picture as a NSData object

    contact.givenName = "John"
    contact.familyName = "Appleseed"

    let homeEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelHome, value:"john@example.com")
    let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value:"j.appleseed@icloud.com")
    contact.emailAddresses = [homeEmail, workEmail]

    contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(
        label:CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone,
        value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:"(408) 555-0126"))]

    return contact
}
```

[image: Activity view controller showing apps which support VCard format]

[image: VCard contact appearing in Messages app]

Comment: Thank you - I just updated my initial post with a new question.  I think your answer will resolve it, though.  I'll try it out and get back to you.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked perfectly.  I understand it now.  I do have one last question, however.  When I share the contact, the .vcf has a long name like "6DD3C04D-08C1-44C7-8A7E-F08C6F0CB5CD.vcf".  Can I get that changed to JohnnyAppleseed.vcf, just like you get when you share a contact from your own address book? EDIT:  Oh, I got it!  I overlooked .URLByAppendingPathComponent(NSUUID().UUIDString).  Thank you so much!

Comment: `CNContactFormatter` will help you there. I have updated the code to show how you might use it. It will fall back to the UUID string if the contact does not have a name (for whatever reason), or if you share multiple contacts at once (in which case using the first name is probably not desired).

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it addressed your question.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a CNContact (requires iOS 9):

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
    contact.givenName = "John"
    contact.familyName = "Doe"
    contact.emailAddresses = [
      CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: "john.doe@email.com")
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

> It is very simple to create contact from your iOS app and share over
>   the external apps.

First you need to create **Share Button Action** like below :-

```
-(void)shareContactAction:(UIButton*)sender
{  
    CNMutableContact *selectedCon = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
    selectedCon.givenName = @"ABC";
    selectedCon.familyName = @"XYZ";
    NSString *phoneNum = @"+91-XXXXXXXXXXX"
    CNLabeledValue *contactNum1 = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:phoneNum]];
    selectedCon.phoneNumbers = @[contactNum1];
    NSString *url=[self saveContactDetailsToDocDir:selectedCon];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Contact", [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];     
}
```

> Than you can call the function below which will return the path of the
>   contact card in above button event.

```
- (NSString *)saveContactDetailsToDocDir:(CNContact *)contact {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * contactCardPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/vCardName.vcf"];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:contact, nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [CNContactVCardSerialization dataWithContacts:array error:&error];
    [data writeToFile:contactCardPath atomically:YES];

    return contactCardPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for Swift 4:**

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {

    let contact = createContact()

    do {
        try shareContacts(contacts: [contact])
    }
    catch {
    // Handle error
    }
}

func shareContacts(contacts: [CNContact]) throws {

    guard let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
    return
    }

    var filename = NSUUID().uuidString

    // Create a human friendly file name if sharing a single contact.
    if let contact = contacts.first, contacts.count == 1 {

    if let fullname = CNContactFormatter().string(from: contact) {
        filename = fullname.components(separatedBy: " ").joined(separator: "")
    }
    }

    let fileURL = directoryURL
    .appendingPathComponent(filename)
    .appendingPathExtension("vcf")

    let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: contacts)

    print("filename: \(filename)")
    print("contact: \(String(describing: String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)))")

    try data.write(to: fileURL, options: [.atomicWrite])

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [fileURL],
    applicationActivities: nil
    )

    present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func createContact() -> CNContact {

    // Creating a mutable object to add to the contact
    let contact = CNMutableContact()

    contact.imageData = NSData() as Data // The profile picture as a NSData object

    contact.givenName = "John"
    contact.familyName = "Appleseed"

    let homeEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelHome, value:"john@example.com")
    let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value:"j.appleseed@icloud.com")
    contact.emailAddresses = [homeEmail, workEmail]

    contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(
    label:CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone,
    value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:"(408) 555-0126"))]

    return contact
}
```

Comment: These methods work for the most part but I can't get a thumbnail or contact image to show. I get this error `QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=0 "Could not generate a thumbnail"` Im using `let image = UIImage(named: "ExistingContactPlaceHolderPic")
            contact.imageData = image?.pngData()` Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Successful approach:

First get all Contacts then save it and after this make .vcf file and also share the .vcf in Emails, WhatsApp, Messaging, Skype and save in iPhone files....

[image]

```
@IBAction func vcfPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let arrayContacts = self.fetchAllContacts()
    self.saveContactsInDocument(contacts: arrayContacts)
     let contact = fetchAllContacts()
     do {
     try shareContacts(contacts: contact)
     }
     catch {
     }
}


func shareContacts(contacts: [CNContact]) throws {

    guard let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
 return}

    var filename = NSUUID().uuidString
    if let contact = contacts.first, contacts.count == 1 {
    if let fullname = CNContactFormatter().string(from: contact) {
    filename = fullname.components(separatedBy: " ").joined(separator: "")}}
    let fileURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(filename).appendingPathExtension("vcf")
    let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: contacts)
    print("filename: \(filename)")
    print("contact: \(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))")
    try data.write(to: fileURL, options: [.atomicWrite])
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL],applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
 }


func fetchAllContacts() -> [CNContact] {

    var contacts : [CNContact] = []
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    let fetchReq = CNContactFetchRequest.init(keysToFetch: [CNContactVCardSerialization.descriptorForRequiredKeys()])
    do {
        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: fetchReq) { (contact, end) in
            contacts.append(contact)
        }}
    catch  {print("Failed to fetch")}
    return contacts
}
```

[image]